# qpaintervideosurface.cpp:99: error: incomplete type 'QOpenGLContext' used in nested name specifier

Tags: opengl, build, qt5

qpaintervideosurface.cpp:99: error: incomplete type 'QOpenGLContext' used in nested name specifier

my configure is "./configure -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests -no-c++11 -no-gtkstyle -no-dbus"

i try it with "-no-opengl",still error.

i dont know why , help me!

Answer (score 0):

i fix it. config without using "-no-opengl"